# How to install windows 7 when laptop only has USB 3.0 ports

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, usb-3, usb-2, hp-envy

I am trying to dual boot my laptop (HP envy) which is currently running windows 10 with windows 7. I continuously got errors during the windows 7 install due to my USB being in a USB 3.0 port. My laptop only has USB 3.0 ports, how would I go about installing windows 7?

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Quote the phrases or errors that say you can't use 3.0? Where exactly during installation does it say this? What specific model of HP Envy? Do you have legacy/secure boot/UEFI enabled or disabled? Can you disable USB related settings in BIOS? Is your hard drive using MBR or GPT partition table?

Answer (score 2):

The default Windows 7 installation image does not feature appropriate USB3.0 drivers. Thus, you need to make them available at the time of installing. [This manual for intel devices](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/mini-pcs/nuc-kits/Install-Win7-to-USB3_0-Computers.pdf) points out how to inject USB3.0 drivers right into the installation image. Remember to allocate the right drivers for your device from [HPs support page](https://support.hp.com/de-de/drivers).

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.